# How view the output of the program running through the service (Centos 7)?

Tags: service, centos, systemd

I can see the status of the service

```
systemctl status name_service.service
```

but I do not know how to see what the program itself is outputting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output (both stdout and stderr) from services by default is redirected to journald.

You can get it as log entries by filtering for the appropriate service:

```
sudo journalctl -u name_service
```